# Mongo-mongoose What is the best way to create categorical type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongo db with nodejs and mongoose.mongoose created id for every record but what I want is identical auto increment type. It will starts from 1 or 0 then increase.

Is there any schema type to make it. It will be used for categorical  result from api.

Thank you.

My attempt is

```
category_type: {
  type     : Number,
  required : true,
  unique   : true,
  validate : {
    validator : Number.isInteger,
    message   : '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
  }
}
```

Can it be incremental?

Answer (score 0):

From mongoose itself(v5 or less), there's no such auto-increment integer schema type. However, I've come across a plugin that can help, check it out here [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment)